# counting sort gives wrong results

Tags: c++, sorting, counting

Counting sort always gives incorrect result, always with a leading 0 and missing the last number, i.e. given input 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, it would give 0, 5, 6, 7, 8.

My logic:

1. Use C as buckets for digits 0-9
2. Tally up items in source array A by C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1
3. Go through all buckets in C and add up all items <= current bucket to find rightful position for A[i]
4. Copy items in C to output array B, remembering to decrement the bucket in C for each copying

// same code used to ask a question earlier, btw, but this is a different question

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 10

int main(void){

    int A[MAX] = {9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 0, 0, 9, 3};
    int C[10];
    int B[MAX] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    C[i] = 0;

    std::cout << "\nOriginal array = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)   std::cout << " " << A[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    //  increment count of buckets containing this digit accordingly
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)   C[A[i]] =  C[A[i]] + 1;

    //  count all count <= the current bucket to determine the correct index
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)    C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1];

    //  copy array elements to output array B and decrement C array accordingly
    for (int i = MAX-1; i >= 0; i--){
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]]-1;
    }

    std::cout << "\nSorted array = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)  std::cout << " " << B[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Results are always wrong, with a leading 0 as the first element, and always missing the last element.

Comment: If I run that, I get the message "*** stack smashing detected ***". You're writing outside at least one array.

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to hone your debugging skills. Step through the program with a debugger and, at each step, check what you expect to happen vs what the program does. When those differ, you have found the bug.

Comment: `B[C[A[i]]]` should probably be `B[C[A[i]] - 1]` as we use 0-indexing..

Comment: @Jarod42 - Sorry, didn't notice your comment! If you post an answer, I'll wipe mine, as you got the fix first.

Comment: @Adrian: No issues. keep your answer. I would have to answer in answer section and not in comment section ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Jarod42** says, your problem is that arrays in C start at index [0], so you are getting the index to your answer array B incorrect. Simple fix:

```
//  copy array elements to output array B and decrement C array accordingly
for (int i = MAX - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//  B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];     // Wrong
    B[C[A[i]] - 1] = A[i]; // Right
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
}
```